# Wordpress permlink show "You should update your web.config now." in godaddy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In Godaddy wordpress site not showing inner pages, It show only home page and wordpress admin page. While click save changes in "Permalink Settings" it show "You should update your web.config now." While I add web.config in my site it show 500 error(Home page and admin page also) Now what to do? fix 500 error or fix 404 error and how to fix? kindly help me.
my .htaccess file is below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: are you using linux server?

Comment: No windows server

Comment: While i add your config file home page and admin page get 500 error another pages show well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are using windows server, so you need web.config in root folder of wordpress,

If web.config not found on root folder, then add web.config file and add the code below into it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

root folder means, the folder which contains wp-content, wp-includes etc.,

If in case, home page is throwing 500 error, then try removing the whole `<defaultDocument>` tag section

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
       <remove value="index.aspx" />
       <add value="index.php" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Comment: Hi.. now home page get 500 error, other pages work fine. What to do?

Comment: 500 error means you placed some wrong code in home page. Please double check

Comment: Try removing the  <defaultDocument> tag, worked for me. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the interior pages working but the homepage throwing a 500 error. I got the homepage to work by editing the web.config file - removing the  tag and everything inside it.